# Não consigo iniciar o MySQL no EasyPHP

Tags: mysql, apache, phpmyadmin, easyphp

Sempre que eu vou utilizar o EasyPHP não consigo dar um start no MySQL sendo que o Apache inicia normalmente. O que eu posso fazer?

[image: Apache starta e mysql não.]

Comment: Dê uma olhada no log do MySQL. Lá eles informam o possível erro que impede a inicialização do MySQL.

Comment: Primeira coisa o log, o Skype costuma parar serviços do MySQL